# Titanium - save image from the internet to SD CARD on Android

Tags: image, save, titanium, appcelerator, sd-card

I have a problem with Titanium Appcelerator & Android. I want to save an image from the internet to my SD CARD. How can I do that ?

```
var externalSrc = "http://example.com/image.jpg";

saveButton.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
//?!?
});
```

Any help would be appreciated, many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the code on Android but on iOS this works well.

```
var c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(directory, filename); // Here is the path to save the file.
var url = '/url/to/image.jpeg';
c.onload = function() {
    // File saved
};

c.ondatastream = function(e) {
    // Progress value in e.progress;
};

c.onerror = function(e) {
    // error
};

c.open('GET', url);  // open the client
c.setFile(f);
c.send();    // send the data
```